# Dynamic image creation using gruff in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, dynamic, gruff

I am new to Ruby on Rails and working on Graph creation using 'Gruff'.
In controller I am writing below code to create image in assets/images.

```
g.write("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/chart/chart.png")
```

and in view : `<%= image_tag("chart/chart.png", :alt => "Image missing") %>`

By using this way I can perfectly see image in the view, but storing images in assets/images will consume a lot of memory.

Is there an alternative to create image dynamically without storing it in assets/images?

Comment: Are you worried about the RAM needed by rmagick to render the image or the disk space?

Answer (score 0):

In the controller instead of writing the image, use:

```
 send_data(g.to_blob, :disposition => 'inline',  :type => 'image/png',  :filename => "chart.png
```

It will not create image but display it on view.